# Regex to recognize integers with 0 before them in Java

Tags: java, regex, imagej

I'm working on a macro in ImageJ that will loop through a series of images with a standard format and merge them together as two different channels. I have the macro written, but I need it to be able to accept different formats of integers as part of the filenames.

Here's the filename format.

Image 1: aSMA neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B01f00d0.TIF

Image 2: aSMA neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B01f00d1.TIF

B01 is the ID for the "well" that the tissue corresponds to. I need a script that can accept "aSMA neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B01f00d1.TIF" and "aSMA neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B11f00d1.TIF" regardless of having the "0" in front of the digit.

Here's the code so far. The directory setting is something I'm still working on.

```
// Get directory of images
//inDir = getDirectory("*\aSMA neut.2022-12-05-22-40-09")

// Set output directory for merged images
//outDir = getDirectory("")

// For loop to go through all images

var well=9;
var image=5;

for (i = 1; i <= well; ++i) {
    for (p = 0; p <= image; ++p) {
        open("*/aSMA neut.2022-12-05-22-40-09/aSMA_neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B0" + i + "f0" + p + "d0.TIF"); // Will need to change i value to account for presence of 0 before single digits
        image1 = getTitle;
        open("*/aSMA neut.2022-12-05-22-40-09/aSMA_neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B0" + i + "f0" + p + "d1.TIF"); // Will need to change i value to account for presence of 0 before single digits
        image2 = getTitle;

        run("Merge Channels...", "c1=" + image1 + " c2=" + image2 + " create keep");
        saveAs("tif", "C:/Users/fgoot/Downloads/OneDrive_2023-07-24/aSMA neut.2022-12-05-22-40-09/merged/aSMA_neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B0" + i + "f0" + p + "d" + "_merged.tif");

        run("Close All");
    
        print(image1);
        print(image2);
        print(i);
    }
}
```

Basically, I need an "01" string to be recognized as a "1".

Edit: added a "0" after B in the filenames in the example. This is what works with values 1-9, but when it gets to 10 or more, there's no "0" after the B.

Comment: The example digits differ only in the "1" or "0" after the "d". Is that how it is supposed to look like?

Comment: Can there be multiple zeroes or only one between the B and the "well" number?

Comment: Yup, d0 and d1 are two different color channels of the same tissue sample, I want to stack the two together.

Comment: @DavidConrad Only one zero.

Comment: In the case of "B11f" then the well number is 11? If this were a Java regex I would just add "0?" after the B, but it seems it is using a shell-style regular expression.

Comment: The current filename only contains one regex syntax, the dot-character.  So, escape that character, and replace the _0_ in the _B01_ with a `\d`.  The pattern would be, `aSMA neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B\d1f00d1\.TIF`.  Would this be a solution; it will match a `\d` with any digit, 0 through 9.

Comment: It would need to match all integers up through 12 at the moment. This is what would need to be recognized:
01, 02, ..., 10, 11, 12

Comment: @Reilas That would match completely different well numbers, but also, look at the beginning of the filename. It starts with `*/`. This looks like a glob syntax for the shell, not a Java regex.

Comment: What regex syntax does `open` take? Is that your method, or part of a library you're using?

Comment: Honestly not sure, it's part of the ImageJ Macro language.

Comment: If it's what I'm looking at, I wonder if it would make sense to call [`getName`](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/ij/io/Opener.html#getName(java.lang.String)) on both `"...B0" + i + "f..."` and on `"...B" + i + "f..."` and use whichever one returns successfully? I'm not sure.

Comment: It looks like the _ImageJ_ syntax includes a string.matches function.  I imagine you can use that to check the filename.

Comment: I found a workaround using an if/else statement; basically, if ```i``` is below 10, the expression is ```aSMA_neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B0" + i + "f0" + p + "d0.TIF```, else it's ```aSMA_neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B" + i + "f0" + p + "d0.TIF```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's understood the question right, even after all the comments I find it a bit confusing.

Maybe you need something like this? Here I added a question mark to the 0 to make it optional. This would also match `011` but not `001`. But maybe that is OK, and 100 files is a maximum for you.
`open("*/aSMA neut.2022-12-05-22-40-09/aSMA_neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B0?" + i + "f0" + p + "d0.TIF");`

You can also produce an exact string to match, using `String.format("%02d", i)`, looking like this:
`open(String.format("*/aSMA neut.2022-12-05-22-40-09/aSMA_neut_Plate_D_p00_0_B%02df0%dd0.TIF", i, p));`